# Is there a Selenium 2 version of Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to **Selenium** and I'm a bit confused about the version numbers.  **Selenium 2.0** was released in 2011.  I just downloaded the **Selenium IDE** Firefox extension and it is version `1.7.2`.  Is there also a 2.0 release of the `IDE`, or does the `1`. x series confusingly contain the `2.0` code?

I checked [Selenium HQ](http://seleniumhq.org/download/), which states that `1.7.2` is currently the latest release of the **Selenium IDE**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Versioning of Selenium releases has always been kind of confusing. The essential difference between Selenium 1 and 2 is that Selenium 1 used the Selenium Remote Control interface, while Selenium 2 is based on WebDriver. That means: Selenium 2 tests are such ones that you write in code, e.g. in Java, in an object-oriented manner. Everything you record or script using the Selenium IDE uses the Selenium RC interface, which still works with Selenium 2 for backwards compatibility. So there is no Selenium IDE 2.

Comment: There is also an option in Options -> WebDriver where you can enable WebDriver playback - so it is close to Selenium 2.

Answer (score 3):

As it happens, I'm actually working on an alternative to Selenium IDE called [Se Builder](https://github.com/admc/se-builder) that does support Selenium 2. It's still under development, but the first beta version is due to be released in the next few days.

Comment: Cool, I'll keep an eye on it too.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Selenium IDE 2.0. You can use Selenium IDE with Selenium 1.0 as well as selenium 2.0

Answer (score 2):

Currently selenium IDE get released only [1.9.0](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/1.9.0/selenium-ide-1.9.0.xpi).

So do not have 2.0 IDE, you can download and update IDE 1.9.0 for firefox.

but Selenium server get released [2.25.0](http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar)

Comment: I don't think there is a connection between major version of Selenium IDE and Selenium itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenium IDE 2.9.x and during exporting code from IDE to java you can export as "Java / TestNG / WebDriver" or "Java / JUnit4 / WebDriver" whatever you need.

You can also convert the code to C#, Python, Ruby etc. Selenium 2 is based on WebDriver.

Comment: The latest version of Selenium IDE is 1.10.0 now

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's also this: https://github.com/samitbadle/seleniumide/, "the latest build of Selenium IDE 2.0 that will be officially released soon".

Its last commit was 2 years ago, so maybe that "soon" aspect never happened. The maintainer wrote quite a bit about it while development was in progress (http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/tag/selenium-2-2/) but nothing under the tag since it was meant to be released.

I haven't run the code yet, but I carefully guess that it's [abandonware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abandonware).

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE 1.7 is the latest version.. which updated with selenium commands and compatible with the firefox ... we dont have any selenium IDE 2 for the same

thanks

Answer (score 0):

latest version of ide is 1.9.0. for the web driver supports you need to download additional formatters like php formatters etc.